# Cannot add less support to Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sass, less

I'm trying to add `LESS` support to Angular 8 project (the project was updated from version 5 by ng update with `SCSS` as default styling library. Now I need to replace `SCSS` with `LESS`. Just change `styleext` section to be `less` doesn't work - I'm getting the error `Error: Cannot find module 'less'`.
How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm i less --save
```

should work for you

Comment: you can give it a try

Comment: It works of course, but I feel like this is kind of hack in this situation.

Comment: Why do you need to install less since angular cli already take care ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your angular.json

```
"projects": {
    "sometest": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": { // this one
          "style": "less"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/sometest",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.less" // also this
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Also change all your style to .less extension then run your server again